# Steadyflow Download Manager

Tags: download-manager

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 and I'm new in linux world. I try to download Steadyflow Download manager, but I want like Internet download manager: when I click it should automatically download it. Notice: I am using Firefox as web browser.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably would like "Xtreme Download Manager". Visually similar to IDM and cross-platform. (You will need OpenJRE)

> Check this link : http://xdman.sourceforge.net

Xtreme download Manager can grab downloads from Firefox. Or you can use FlashGot addon in conjunction with the download managers listed here - http://flashgot.net/features

Comment: I presonally prefer "Axel" and "Prozilla".

Answer (score 0):

The best download manager for Linux is uGet. It ie probably the closest to IDM and or even has some cool features that IDM doesn't.

Give it a try by going to http://uGetdm.com/downloads-ubuntu

Comment: uGet can not support Sitelogins

Comment: You are incorrect. It does support site-logins. Create a new category -> go to "Default for new download 1" tab -> Login | http://i.imgur.com/YHtYiBp.png